# $f:\mathbb{R^N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Definition of Partial Derivative Using Limit or Epsilon

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone share the exact definition of partial derivative for a function $f:\mathbb{R^N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in both limit language and epsilon-delta language?

In particular, I have hard time understanding say,

> Suppose $\frac{\partial f(x^*)}{\partial x_n} = a>0$ where $x^*$ is a local max/min of $f$.

Using the epsilon-delta definition getting to the contradiction the above assumption would mean that $f$ is locally increasing around $x^*$ in the direction of the $n^{th}$ coordinate axis.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an exact definition of the partial derivative in derivative language; you know that an ordinary derivative is a certain limit and you know how to define limits in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, so that should suffice.

Say $e_n=(0,0\dots,0,1,0,0,\dots,0)$, the vector with every coordinate equal to $0$ except the $n$-th, which equals $a$. Define $\phi:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by $$\phi(t)=f(x^*+te_n).$$Then by definition $$\frac{\partial f(x^*)}{\partial x_n}=\phi'(0).$$